# separate layout equally

Tags: android, listview, layout

I've got this code that i'm working on :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:weightSum="3"
android:id="@+id/main"
>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="330dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/linear1"
>
    <TextView 
        android:text="List1"
        android:textSize="40px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/shows_text"
    />
    <ListView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/listView1" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_below="@id/shows_text"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="330dp" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/linear2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/linear1"
>
    <TextView 
        android:text="List2"
        android:textSize="40px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/seasons_text"
    />
    <ListView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/listView2" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/seasons_text"         
    />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="330dp" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/linear3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/linear2"
>
    <TextView 
        android:text="List3"
        android:textSize="40px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/episodes_text"
    />
    <ListView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/listView3" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/episodes_text"
    />
</RelativeLayout>

   </RelativeLayout>
```

And this layout doesn't seperate the listview equally, i tried to pu some weight on the layouts but there is a little space that i can't get rid of .

Comment: im sure someone has already told you this, but its poor programming to use px instead of dp or sp. also, im pretty sure weight has no impact on `RelativeLayout` but i could be wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using layout_weight property properly... use parent root layout as LinearLayout and set its orientation as horizontal. I guess that can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change the layout_width to 0dip when you are using weight to have them automatically sized.  Also, you may want to change the layout_width of your TextViews to fill_parent to be consistent with the width of your listview.